# Python zmq (ZeroMQ) bind fails silently

Tags: python, zeromq

In C, ZeroMQ's various calls return error codes.

But if the following Python is executed in two processes in one server, then the second process fails - completely silently. How can I detect this situation?

a) Why is it not raising an error?

b) Why do none of the Python ZMQ calls return status codes, if they don't assert?

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5556")
socket.send("Hello world")
```

Answer (score 0):

**a)** the respective ZeroMQ **[python-binding](http://zeromq.org/bindings:python)** author decided whether or not to raise it.

user always has options to inspect the **`zmq_errno()`**, hasn't she/he?

**b)** again, no one's but the python-binding author's Hamlet decision - to do or not to do so.

Conservative design schools advice to be rather explicit on resource-mapping in **`.bind()`** method calls. An explicitly controlled mapping ought under a due design practice never collide on resources-mapping when `.bind()`-ing, ought it?